# assigning string to a property of string type C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I can better explain my problem by code
here it is

```
strind abc="12345678<9";
row1ViewModel data = new row1ViewModel();
data.identityType = abc[0].ToString();
data.passportType = abc[1].ToString();
data.issuingOrg = abc.Substring(2, 3);
var  actual = "";
data.lastName = actual;
//data.lastName = actual;
if (abc[5] == '<')
{
    actual = "Not specified";
}
else
{
    string tempq = abc.Substring(5);
    int index = tempq.IndexOf('<');
    actual = abc.Substring(5, index);
}
//data.GetType().GetProperty(data.lastName).GetValue(actual,null)
```

Here I need to set my property (data.lastname of string type) to a string actual value. But how?

Comment: You have already done that: `data.lastName = actual;`. What's not happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: I got my ans. (doing wrong)i am filling data.lastname with empty actual string before executing if else statement ...(solution)place data.lastname after executing if and else statement so that actual supply updated value to data.lastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your

```
 data.lastName = actual;
```

to after your else loop, if im reading your logic correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have first assigned empty string property:

```
var  actual = "";
     data.lastName = actual;
```

and then update the value of actual, but the property still has "" as it's value
You should just move

```
data.lastName = actual;
```

to the end of the code:

```
         strind abc="12345678<9";
     row1ViewModel data = new row1ViewModel();
   data.identityType = abc[0].ToString();
      data.passportType = abc[1].ToString();
      data.issuingOrg = abc.Substring(2, 3);
      var  actual = "";          
     //data.lastName = actual;
      if (abc[5] == '<')
      {
          actual = "Not specified"; 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         string tempq = abc.Substring(5);
          int index = tempq.IndexOf('<'); 
         actual = abc.Substring(5, index); 
       } 
     //data.GetType().GetProperty(data.lastName).GetValue(actual,null)`  
     data.lastName = actual;
```